# how to pass user information to a web service using REST

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I have this method...

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
    context.MapRoute("AccesoCliente", "Api/Clientes/Cliente/{id}", new {
        controller = "Clien`enter code here`tes",
        action = "Cliente",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

... It allow me to give an url pass an id and perform certain methods. But I want to pass name and password to create a login. I do not now how to make this part

```
"Api/Clientes/Cliente/{id}",
```

To have name and password or have should I construct this mapRoute nor know by what tags should I google it. If you can help, giving a direct response or any link to tutorials about this topic, I would greatly appreciate it.